# blackberry switching app from 4.5 to 4.6

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have this application developed for Blackberry 4.5. 
I´m using Eclipse, and I want to test my application for blackberry 4.6.

What´s the easy way to generate the alx and cod file to install my app for this version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding all 4.5 features will work on 4.6.  One of the easiest ways is to use a simulator that would have 4.6 as the OS or just run your current version on a new device with 4.6 installed.

Comment: echo that. if built for 4.5 you can run same .cod "as is" on 4.6, 4.7, 5.0... and so on.

Comment: The only Device where you need a 5.0 compile .COD is on the Storm.

Answer (score 0):

As  Michael B said You will have some compatibility issue for 5.0 but however you can disable compatibility from application settings. It will work as expected.

Few of the touch specific compatibility issue will be still there until you build in 5.0.